# An equivalence of Big O definition and moderate decrease

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Given a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, let's say that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $|x|\to\infty$ when there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C|g(x)|$ for all $x$ sufficiently large. Also, given a fixed $\epsilon>0$, $f$ is of moderate decrease if there exists $A>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le \frac{A}{1+|x|^{1+\epsilon}}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to know whether these definitions are equivalent in the case I choose $g(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^{1+\alpha}}$, for some fixed $0<\alpha<1$.

I know that that the second property implies the first, because $\frac{1}{1+|x|^{1+\alpha}}\le\frac{1}{|x|^{1+\alpha}}$.

For the converse, I think that, given that $f$ is continuous on $[-B,B]$ and decays outside this interval for some $B>0$, then it seems we could choose some $A>0$ such that we could assure $|f(x)|\le \frac{A}{1+|x|^{1+\alpha}}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. But I'm struggling to prove this. Can someone give some light on how to do it, or if this is not true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: when $|x|\ge1$, we have $1+|x|^{1+\alpha} \le 2|x|^{1+\alpha}$.